# limiting to 2 places, tofixed not working

Tags: javascript

.toFixed(2).

I have this working fine, I get my accurate answers.

```
        var la_95_m = document.getElementById("la_95_charge_m");
la_95_m.value = (((total_current_storage.value / total_current_draw_30.value) / cd5_factor) * bc_95_sd_ad) * new_old_factor;
```

I need to wrap the "var la_95_m" with toFixed(2) but no matter how I have tried it I keep breaking the script.

all of these

```
var la_95_m.toFixed(2);

var la_95_m.value.toFixed(2);

var la_95_m.toFixed(2) = document.getElementById("la_95_charge_m");
                    la_95_m.value = (((total_current_storage.value / total_current_draw_30.value) / cd5_factor) * bc_95_sd_ad) * new_old_factor;
```

break it.

Any tips/help is appreciated

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Examples

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare variables to have a type that is [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), so variations on:

```
var la_95_m.toFixed(2)
```

will *not* work.

You need to call `.toFixed(2)` on the result of your calculation:

```
var result = (((total_current_storage.value / total_current_draw_30.value) / cd5_factor) * bc_95_sd_ad) * new_old_factor;
la_95_m.value = result.toFixed(2);
```

Where `result` contains a numeric value, `result.toFixed(2)` returns a string that is the number with two decimal places. (If `result` is *not* numeric you'll get an error.)

To do that without creating an extra `result` variable, wrap your calculation in parentheses and call `.toFixed(2)` on that:

```
la_95_m.value = (someExpressionThatIsNumeric).toFixed(2);

la_95_m.value = ((((total_current_storage.value / total_current_draw_30.value) / cd5_factor)
                 * bc_95_sd_ad) * new_old_factor).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var la_95_m.toFixed(2);` to `la_95_m.value = la_95_m.value.toFixed(2);`.

`.toFixed(n)` doesn't actually change the value of the number you're calling it on, it merely returns a new string with n digits.